# How to obfuscate request properties in tomcat log file

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, logging, obfuscation

I have a rest based weapp that runs on tomcat. Every time i hit some of the rest endpoints on the server - a log with the request details is written in the log file. How can i configure tomcat to obfuscate the sended values of the json request. Ex.

Instead of:  { "country": "USA" }
To be: {"country":"******"}

Thanks!

Comment: with log4j.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461726/how-to-mask-credit-card-numbers-in-log-files-with-log4j

Answer (score 1):

inorder to apply masking on filter . you need to perform something like this..
http://vozis.blogspot.com/2012/02/log4j-filter-to-mask-payment-card.html